# Excluse specific IPs from Website with .htaccess restriction

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, webserver, restriction

I want to grant public access to a hosted Website (nginx) and exclude a specific IP-Address range (123.456) from accessing it.

To say it simple: Every access from the IP-Range 123.456 should be restricted by promting for Username/Password. Thats what I want to have.

Here my .htaccess.

```html
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Go away!"
AuthUserFile /home/www/path-to-my/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 123.456
Satisfy any
```

What I get when I am using it:

- Public access successful
- Access from the excluded IP-Range = Timeout

Comment: Solved! Had to restart the machine!

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I know .htaccess files are only for apache web server and not nginx.

Yo'll need to convert the rules with [a converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) or do it yourself.

In your case:

```
# nginx configuration
auth_basic "Go away!";
auth_basic_user_file /home/www/path-to-my/.htpasswd;
deny 123.456;
satisfy any;
```

The configuration directives are quite similar, but they are different.